# Writing custom instances for JSON date data in Aeson

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I have JSON date data in the following form:

```
  {"date": "2015-04-12"}
```

and a corresponding haskell type:

```
data Date = Date {
      year   :: Int
    , month  :: Int
    , day    :: Int
    }
```

How can I write the custom `FromJSON` and `ToJSON` functions for the 
[Aeson](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.6.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html) library?
Deriving the instances does not work because of the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have convert y/m/d to/from string

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-tabs #-}

import Control.Monad
import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Text.Read (readMaybe)
-- import qualified Data.Attoparsec.Text as A

data Date = Date Int Int Int deriving (Read, Show)

instance ToJSON Date where
    toJSON (Date y m d) = toJSON $ object [
        "date" .= T.pack (str 4 y ++ "-" ++ str 2 m ++ "-" ++ str 2 d)]
        where
            str n = pad . show where
                pad s = replicate (n - length s) '0' ++ s

instance FromJSON Date where
    parseJSON = withObject "date" $ \v -> do
        str <- v .: "date"
        let
            ps@(~[y, m, d]) = T.split (== '-') str
        guard (length ps == 3)
        Date <$> readNum y <*> readNum m <*> readNum d
        where
            readNum = maybe (fail "not num") return . readMaybe . T.unpack

    -- -- or with attoparsec
    -- parseJSON = withObject "date" $ \v -> do
    --  str <- v .: "date"
    --  [y, m, d] <- either fail return $
    --      A.parseOnly (A.decimal `A.sepBy` A.char '-') str
    --  return $ Date y m d
```

Answer (score 9):

Why reinvent the wheel? There is a semi-standard representation for what you call `Date` in the [`time`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time) package - it is called [`Day`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time/docs/Data-Time-Calendar.html#t:Day). It gets better: not only does that same package even give you the utilities for parsing `Day` from the format you have, those utilities are even exported to `aeson`. Yep, there are already `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` instances in `aeson` for `Day`:

```
ghci> :set -XOverloadedStrings
ghci> import Data.Time.Calendar
ghci> import Data.Aeson
ghci> fromJSON "2015-04-12" :: Result Day
Success 2015-04-12
ghci> toJSON (fromGregorian 2015 4 12)
String "2015-04-12"
```

If you *really* want to extract the days, months, and years, you can always use [`toGregorian :: Day -> (Integer, Int, Int)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.6.0.1/docs/Data-Time-Calendar.html#v:toGregorian). Sticking to the standard abstraction is probably a good long-term choice though.